# How to provide firebase admin credentials to Netlify?

Tags: netlify, sveltekit

I tried to configure the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` environment variable on Netlify in order to use `firebase-admin`, but how do I get the actual JSON file there?

Obviously I cannot include it in git.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can generate the admin credential certificate by piecing the credentials together using environment variables.

You will have to provide the project specific values to the Netlify runtime using Netlify's [environment mechanism](https://docs.netlify.com/configure-builds/environment-variables/)

and then instantiate the admin client like this

```js
import admin, { app, AppOptions } from "firebase-admin";

const config: AppOptions = {
  credential: admin.credential.cert({
    projectId: process.env["FIREBASE_ADMIN_PROJECT_ID"],
    clientEmail: process.env["FIREBASE_ADMIN_CLIENT_EMAIL"],
    privateKey: process.env["FIREBASE_ADMIN_PRIVATE_KEY"].replace(/\\n/g, "\n"),
  }),
  // databaseURL: process.env.SVELTE_APP_FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL,
};

let firebaseAdminApp: app.App;

if (!admin.apps.length) {
  firebaseAdminApp = admin.initializeApp(config);
} else {
  firebaseAdminApp = admin.app();
}

export default firebaseAdminApp;
```

Comment: +1 Awesome, thank you! I actually made it work using a bash script that generates the credential file on build from environment variables, but your approach looks much cleaner.